# Calculate amount of periods with 10 minutes slice in Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Suppose I have a table with `play` and `stop` fields where both of them are timestamp, let's say each row is a user session somewhere:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE "#times" (
  play timestamp,
  stop timestamp
);
INSERT INTO #times (play, stop)
values
    ('2010-08-07 08:49:19', '2010-08-07 09:49:19'),
    ('2023-08-07 08:49:19', '2023-08-07 09:11:19'),
    ('2023-08-07 08:59:19', '2023-08-07 09:05:19'),
    ('2023-08-07 09:33:19', '2023-08-07 09:50:19'),
    ('2023-08-07 09:39:19', '2023-08-07 10:11:19'),
    ('2023-08-07 09:49:19', '2023-08-07 11:49:19'),
    ('2023-08-07 10:49:19', '2023-08-07 11:20:19');
```

As an output, I want to have number of sessions with some time step, e.g. 10 minutes:

```
+--------+----------+-----+
|sessions|date      |time |
+--------+----------+-----+
|1       |2010-08-07|08:40|
|1       |2010-08-07|08:50|
|1       |2010-08-07|09:00|
|1       |2010-08-07|09:10|
|1       |2010-08-07|09:20|
|1       |2010-08-07|09:30|
|1       |2010-08-07|09:40|
|1       |2023-08-07|08:40|
|2       |2023-08-07|08:50|
|2       |2023-08-07|09:00|
|1       |2023-08-07|09:10|
|2       |2023-08-07|09:30|
|3       |2023-08-07|09:40|
|3       |2023-08-07|09:50|
|2       |2023-08-07|10:00|
|2       |2023-08-07|10:10|
|1       |2023-08-07|10:20|
|1       |2023-08-07|10:30|
|2       |2023-08-07|10:40|
|2       |2023-08-07|10:50|
|2       |2023-08-07|11:00|
|2       |2023-08-07|11:10|
|2       |2023-08-07|11:20|
|1       |2023-08-07|11:30|
|1       |2023-08-07|11:40|
+--------+----------+-----+
```

Currently I store hours/minutes in separate tables like:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE #hours (
    type_id smallint,
    hour VARCHAR(2)
);

INSERT INTO #hours (type_id, hour)
VALUES
    (1, '00'),(1, '03'),(1, '06'),(1, '09'),(1, '12'),(1, '15'),(1, '18'),(1, '21'),
    (2, '00'),(2, '01'),(2, '02'),(2, '03'),(2, '04'),(2, '05'),(2, '06'),(2, '07'),
    (2, '08'),(2, '09'),(2, '10'),(2, '11'),(2, '12'),(2, '13'),(2, '14'),(2, '15'),
    (2, '16'),(2, '17'),(2, '18'),(2, '19'),(2, '20'),(2, '21'),(2, '22'),(2, '23');

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE #minutes (
    type_id smallint,
    minute VARCHAR(2)
);

INSERT INTO #minutes (type_id, minute)
VALUES
    (1, '00'),(2, '00'),(2, '10'),(2, '20'),(2, '30'),(2, '40'),(2, '50');
```

And have a SQL smth like:

```
select
  count(*) as sessions,
  TRUNC("play") as date,
  (HOUR.HOUR || ':' || MINUTE.MINUTE) as "time"
from
  #times,
  (
    select hour from #hours where type_id = 2
  ) HOUR,
  (
      select minute from #minutes where type_id = 2
  ) MINUTE
where (
  "time" >= TO_CHAR("play" - (10 || 'minute')::interval, 'HH24:MI')
  and "time" <= TO_CHAR("stop", 'HH24:MI')
)
group by
  TRUNC("play"),
  "time"
order by date, time;
```

And problem with this SQL is that it has a Cartesian product - loop of mapping every row to every row that is expensive for Redshift.

Is there a way to simplify this query by receiving the same result?

Comment: You may not need the hours minutes tables, unless you want to have intervals with no sessions, as well.

Comment: Maybe :) I'm not saying that this is the right way to do that, it's just a way how I do it now.

Answer (score 2):

This problem reoccurs in many different scenarios and yes the data explosion of the cross product can result in massive intermediate data segments which will bog things down.

I had a client with this problem many years ago and worked out a non-cartesian method.  This reduced their query time from 90 minutes to 17 seconds but the approach requires some "modified" thinking about the query.  This was so effective I added it to my advanced Redshift training course and wrote up a white paper on this approach.

Rather than rewriting this paper I'll just point to it here - https://www.wadevelopment.co/sql_limits_wp.html

The analogy I used to come up with this solution was to think about performing the analysis by hand.  I wouldn't create a record for each 10 minute interval and how many sessions are active in each but rather note the start and end times and which interval they fall in.  Then count the number of starts per interval and ends per interval and subtract the running totals.

Take a look and see if this is good approach for your situation and I'm happy to clarify any points if they are confusing.

Comment: Yeah, that's close to what I need to, thanks for sharing :)
However, with my case when I need also to add a split per client (additional column in initial table) I faced with a wrong numbers: some rows have nulls. And if user session is longer than 10 mins (e.g. 08:39 - 11:12) it doesn't appear in 08:50, 09:00, etc. with correct clientId :-( Didn't figure out how to fix that yet...

Comment: The code in the white paper does work when the "start" and "end" span an interval.  I suspect that something is off when you added client to the mix so let's move to that.  I've done this with the code as well but if the number of "client" values is very very large the intermediate data will be nearly as large as the cross product in the original case.  If the values of "client" are more manageable then this approach works and gives a (somewhat smaller) performance increase.  You will need to create a table (or CTE) with all the intervals cross joined with all the client values.